# Is there any function to fetch real-time downloaded size during the downloading process without using any buffer operation in powershell

Tags: powershell, progress-bar, buffer, invoke-webrequest

```
#Progress bar script of PowerShell to download Kubescape
$fullurl='https://github.com/kubescape/kubescape/releases/download/v2.0.168/kubescape-windows-latest'
$Total_size=((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fullurl -Method Head).Headers).'Content-Length'
$Downloaded_size=0
while($Downloaded_size -lt $Total_size){
$downloaded_percentage= ((100/$Total_size)*$Downloaded_size)+1
[MATH]::Floor($downloaded_percentage)
$Downloaded_size += ?
}
```

here is how to fetch real-time downloaded size during the downloading process without using any buffer operation.

Comment: In the code you provided you haven't even started downloading the file yet. There's nothing to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

As per ***Jesse's*** download comment and my $Total_size comment, your refactor could be this:

```
$fullurl    = 'https://github.com/kubescape/kubescape/releases/download/v2.0.168/kubescape-windows-latest'
$Total_size = ((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fullurl -Method Head).Headers).'Content-Length'
Invoke-WebRequest $fullurl -OutFile "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\kubescape-windows-latest"
```

The above will of course auto-show a progress bar in the console/ISE/VSCode.

Comment: but I need a progress bar that shows me how much percentage is downloaded and how much is remaining